# How to share a rust unpublished cdy lib into Buildroot and use it

Tags: linux, rust, buildroot, rust-crates

When you create a custom rust library package into buildroot 2021, and you want to use it into another rust app package, you have to specify its path into Cargo.toml.
The problem is buildroot package build path changed according to your workspace, and the buildroot version of your package (In the Cargo.toml, you specify: libxxx = { path = "../../libxxx-"}).
Is there a way to inform cargo how to resolve the libxx path without specifying this path ?